# Moving common groupId of modules under the same parent pom to a single place in Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

say I have a parent project (pom only) and several modules. How do you not to repeat the same groupId inside the module poms knowing that the groupId can be inherited from their parent but I also want to add the parent artifactId to the modules' groupId end.

e.g. Inside parent pom, I have

```
<groupId>my.proj</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
```

Then in each modules, right now, I need to write

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<groupId>my.proj.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>mod-a</artifactId>
```

for each module. But what I want is to get rid of the common groupId (best if parent can be removed as well, but I know that is not possible in current Maven), and just write

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>mod-a</artifactId>
```

to automatically receive a groupId of my.proj.xyz instead of just my.proj, because that makes more sense to keep the modules under the parent as oppose to keeping them side by side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not advised to parametrize the `groupId`. Also, that's not what you asked for, because you just don't want to list that entry altogether. It would require changing the way Maven works, and personally I find it unlikely that you're ever going to get your way, as the impact would be too big.

Now, you can already leave out the `groupId` if it's the same as the parent.

Perhaps you can change from calling your parent `com.proj:xyz` to `com.proj.xyz:parent` to fix his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you cannot inherit the group from parent and in same time change it. You could use the parents `groupId` and `artifactId` as property in modules `groupId`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<groupId>${project.parent.groupId}.${project.parent.artifactId}</groupId>
<artifactId>mod-a</artifactId>
```

but you still need to add the `groupId`-element to pom.xml. Also maven complains that `groupId` should not contain expression but a constant.

I would suggest naming the parent `my.proj.xyz:xyz-parent` so the modules can directly inherit parents `groupId`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have written your structure looks like this:

```
   +-- groupId: my.proj artifactId: xyz
        +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId: mod-a
        +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId: mod-b
        +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId: mod-c
        +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId: mod-a
        +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId: mod-b
        +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId: mod-c
```

which is an indicator for changing your structure to something like this:

```
   +-- groupId: my.proj artifactId: xyz
        +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId:abc-parent
        !    +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId: mod-a
        !    +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId: mod-b
        !    +--- groupId: my.proj.abc artifactId: mod-c
        !
        +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId:xyz-parent
             +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId: mod-a
             +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId: mod-b
             +--- groupId: my.proj.xyz artifactId: mod-c
```

which will result in having the poms look like this:

parent pom.xml:

```
<groupId>my.proj</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
<version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
  <module>abc-parent</module>
  <module>xyz-parent</module>
</modules>
```

your abc-parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>my.proj.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc-root</artifactId>
```

your abc-mod-a:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-root</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>mod-a</artifactId>
```

your xyz-parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>my.proj.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-root</artifactId>
```

your xyz-mod-a:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.proj.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-root</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>mod-a</artifactId>
```

Usually changing the groupId in every module is an indicator for having a different module structure.